# Easiest way to merge several modules (jars) into single jar file in Maven 2

Tags: maven, maven-2

Using [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) you can actually merge all dependency jars into single jar file. However I just want to merge several jar files (not all), similary like include-only x, and y, exclude others.

Is there any easiest way to specify only jar file(s) to be included, than to specify all jar files to be excluded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maven-shade-plugin supports both inclusion and exclusion in its parameter [artifactSet](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#artifactSet) - isn't that working as you require ?

```xml
...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-shaded</finalName>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                                <include>net.sf.buildbox:*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
...
```

Comment: does it mean if i specify packages in <includes> tags, other packages would be automatically excluded? last time i tried it those packages were not specified in <includes> tags still merged into jar, however, my pom file might be wrong either in this case.

Comment: yes. Just for sure I tested it right now and it really works as expected - if you specify inclusions only, everything else is excluded.